# Change page URL structure based on node field value

Tags: 7, uri

I'm using Pathauto to produce nice URLs for my Drupal 7 site, and have run into the need to edit the URLs based on a node field value.

Specifically, when the content is archived on my website, the URL needs to be automatically changed to include the substring 'archive'. So when editing this page:

```
www.mysite.com/mypage
```

and `node:field-status` is changed from `none` to `archived`, I need the URL to become:

```
www.mysite.com/archive/mypage
```

Also, pages that already feature a substring, such as `mysite.com/blog/mypage` would ideally have the new substring prepended to the relative URL, so:

```
www.mysite.com/archive/blog/mypage
```

I have tried using Flags and Rules to rewrite the URL pattern based on the field value, but with no luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can build a small module, called `myalias` and use this code to generate custom alias

```
<?php
function myalias_node_insert($node){
    //here you can access the $node variable and get its fields value  
    $node->path['alias'] = 'your_custom_path';
}
```

You can also change the hook to `myalias_node_update($node)` to alter the node alias once it is updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`hook_pathauto_pattern_alter()`](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/pathauto/tree/pathauto.api.php?id=HEAD#n164). Something like this should work for a boolean field (untested)...

```
/**
 * Alter the pattern to be used before an alias is generated by Pathauto.
 *
 * This hook will only be called if a default pattern is configured (on
 * admin/config/search/path/patterns).
 *
 * @param string $pattern
 *   The alias pattern for Pathauto to pass to token_replace() to generate the
 *   URL alias.
 * @param array $context
 *   An associative array of additional options, with the following elements:
 *   - 'module': The module or entity type being aliased.
 *   - 'op': A string with the operation being performed on the object being
 *     aliased. Can be either 'insert', 'update', 'return', or 'bulkupdate'.
 *   - 'source': A string of the source path for the alias (e.g. 'node/1').
 *   - 'data': An array of keyed objects to pass to token_replace().
 *   - 'type': The sub-type or bundle of the object being aliased.
 *   - 'language': A string of the language code for the alias (e.g. 'en').
 *     This can be altered by reference.
 */
function MYMODULE_pathauto_pattern_alter(&$pattern, array $context) {
  // Exit if we don't care about this entity type and bundle.
  if ($context['module'] != 'node' || $context['type'] != 'article') {
    return;
  }

  // Exit if the archive field doesn't exist or isn't set.
  $node = $context['data']['node'];
  assert('$node');
  $items = field_get_items($context['module'], $node, 'FIELDNAME');
  if ($items === FALSE || empty($items[0]['value']) {
    return;
  }

  // Modify the pattern.
  // (I'd try to avoid hardcoding any patterns in this code, but rather use
  // variables. These can either be updated programatically or tied to a UI
  // element.)
  $pattern = '...';
}
```

Comment: I'd love to see an answer to this for Drupal 8. I imagine it's similar.